# Persistent vandalism of professor's office, weak support from security. What steps to take next?

Tags: workplace

For three days in a row, someone has defecated in my office after hours.

I am tenured faculty at a small private school. There is no security camera in the area of my office and security has made half-hearted attempts to discover who is doing this to me.

My personal feeling is that someone (if not everyone) knows who is doing this and will not tell me. Any advice on this issue is appreciated.  I am a productive faculty member but do not take part in social activities and have had run ins with several other faculty so I am not a popular figure in my department. For that reason it is hard to pinpoint who would be a likely suspect, and also probably explains the half-hearted attempt of security to get to the bottom of this. To be clear, I have never done anything like this or been physically abusive to anyone. My conflicts with co-workers are more related to process issues and disagreement on strategy.

What are my options for dealing with this situation? Neither cleaning up the vandalism myself every morning nor hiding in my office to catch the culprit is a practical solution for me.

Comment: Can't you lock your office or something? At least that would reduce the possible culprits to people who have access to your keys (securty members).

Comment: Why don't you set up a camera yourself? There are many cheap solutions nowadays.

Comment: @ViníciusNovelli: At my school, custodians (janitors) also have keys to all the offices.

Comment: Motorola makes a pet/baby camera that you can hide discretely and monitor from your iPhone, and take a picture of the culprit, without them being aware. If a picture of the harasser doesn't convince your chair and/or security to take the matter seriously, there's always the local news.

Comment: This question is cross-posted on [Workplace SE](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/83292/1193)

Comment: On the cross-posted question on Workplace.SE (see scaaahu's comment above), OP claims: "I work at a relatively small company with no HR department", which proves that this is clearly a troll.

Comment: (Not enough rep to comment) With all due respect to those who are calling "troll", does it really matter whether or not the post is, strictly speaking, true? This is an issue of workplace harassment that an academic could face and thus the question could be useful to a future reader. Everyone should chill.

Comment: Most of Stack Exchange discourages speculative questions. If it isn't a real situation, it's considered impolite to ask people to waste their time on it. If it happens "someday", the question can be asked then;  until that time it falls in the category of "anything is possible but most things are not worth planning for."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the right answer would be to report it and let the school deal with it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the poster cannot decide if this is happening at a private school or a small company (based on cross-post).

Comment: @user67917 Extending on keshlam's accurate comment, a question about a hypothetical situation *might* be OK if it was clearly pointed out that the situation is hypothetical. Conversely, the English language has a word for claiming that something happened when it actually didn't: a lie.

Comment: Find out whether it's against the law, and, if so, call the police. After all, it's their job to resolve the situation, and you are paying taxes for that.

Answer (score 12):

Three words: [hostile work environment](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostile_work_environment). Mention these magic words in an email to your department chair, accompanied by a description of the problem (include a photo for good measure), cc'ed to the university's chief legal counsel. Problem solved, or your employers have one major shitstorm (pun intended) of a lawsuit coming their way.

Comment: The chair might not be exactly the right person, but *somebody* is.  Is there a faculty ombudsman?  Head of H-R?  Etc.  Also report to the university police, security, or public safety. Especially in the U.S., be sure to mention Dan's magic words.

Comment: @BobBrown the chair is OP's direct supervisor (in a legal sense, though in practice tenured faculty are a notoriously unsupervised bunch), so as far as my legal understanding goes, that would be _precisely_ the right person to go to, and it would then be the chair's responsibility (which the cc to the legal counsel would ensure they follow up on) to pass the baton along to HR or whoever the case may be. Disclaimer: I am not a lawyer, but I am a department chair.

Comment: If it exists at your university, you might also try going to Occupational Health and Safety.  You are exposed to disease via having to clean up what is essentially toxic waste.  They will have to clean it up for you, and they will really be angry at whoever did that...  You should not clean it up yourself.  I wouldn't clean up feces, blood or anything like that myself.